# JMeter XPath Extractor 2.11

Tags: xml, xpath, jmeter

I am trying to extract several value from my xml response, regular expression extractor doesn't seem to work.

I want to try this but I am an XPath Newbie and I know enough about XML.  A snippet of the xml code I am trying to do an extract from.

```
<entry>
    <string>equipmentName</string>
    <string>JPP</string>
</entry>
```

What I cant understand in all the docs I read is what the XPath query?

Is there anything anyone can suggest?  W need to extract the JPP part of this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible XPath queries you can use to get `JPP`, depending on how you want to identify the element. For example, we can identify `JPP` element as the last `<string>` child of `<entry>` :

```
//entry/string[last()]
```

and of course, you can also identify the element by it's value like so :

```
//entry/string[.='JPP']
```

...while this is possible, I don't think selecting element by value is desirable here because you have to know the value in the first place.

XPath is another topic that you can learn independently, and later use it on various platform including JMeter. Use an XPath tester of your choice, put random XML and some random XPath, and see what the XPath return :

- [w3schools XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp)<sup>*</sup>
- [XPath tester from freeformatter.com](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)<sup>**</sup>

<sub>*) side note: w3schools doesn't have relation to the W3C. I recommend this just because the tutorial is easy to follow and concise, to get you started with XPath</sub>
<sub>**) No particular reason for using this XPath tester, just happened to be the first tester I found.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for "JPP" where parent string is "equipmentName" your XPath query should look as follows:

```
//entry/string[text()='equipmentName']/../string[2]/text()
```

See [XPath 1.0 Language Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) and [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guides for more details.

N.B. above XPath query is for reference only, it may or may not work on your actual data, especially if there are namespaces defined, if it doesn't play for your - update your question with full XML response.

Comment: Actually, then the path expression should look like `//entry[string = 'equipmentName']/string[2]/text()`.